# Select list item parent without children in nested lists in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this nested list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1A</li>
      <li>Item 1B</li>
      <li>Item 1C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2A</li>
      <li class="active">Item 2B</li>
      <li>Item 2C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3
    <ul>
      <li>Item 3A</li>
      <li>Item 3B</li>
      <li>Item 3C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I need is: When I hover on a list item with `class="active"`, this specific item 'Item 2B' together with its parent 'Item 2' to be colored red. 'Item 2A' and 'Item 2C' should **NOT** be colored.

I tried `closest()`:

```
$("li").on("mouseenter", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
        $(this).closest("ul").closest("li").css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

Also `parent().parent()`:

```
$(this).parent().parent().css("color", "red");
```

but of course they both color the whole 'Item 2' list item including all children 2A, 2B and 2C

Comment: For this to work you will need to wrap the `Item 2` text in a containing element, such as a `span`, otherwise the colour of all child elements will  be changed too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Or – using this markup – one has to overwrite the styles for any childs of a parent that is active.

Comment: You may get the larger parent background still showing through with that method

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap each of the parent element into some html element like div or span.

[**Solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/wudegh4j/)

**HTML**

```
 <ul>
              <li>Item 1
                  <ul>
                  <li>Item 1A</li>
                  <li>Item 1B</li>
                  <li>Item 1C</li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li><span>Item 2</span>  
                  <ul>
                      <li>Item 2A</li>
                      <li class="active">Item 2B</li>
                      <li>Item 2C</li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Item 3
                  <ul>
                  <li>Item 3A</li>
                  <li>Item 3B</li>
                  <li>Item 3C</li>
                  </ul>              
              </li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("li").on("mouseenter", function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {

            $(this).css("color", "red");
            $(this).parent().parent().find("span").css("color", "red");
        }          
    });
```

Comment: This is clearly not working in the fiddle example...?

Comment: Thanks. That actually was so basic!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Worked for me. Your solution as well.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually i copied wrong fiddle url. Updated the fiddle link

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't know but sometimes jsfiddle behaves nasty I have faced this issue many times

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you will need to wrap the `Item 2` text in a containing element, such as a `span`, otherwise the colour of all child elements will  be changed too.

Then you can use `.parent.closest('li')` to get the `li`, before using `children()` to retrieve that `span`. Try this:

```js
$("ul").on("mouseenter mouseleave", 'li.active', function(e) {
  var $target = $(this).parent().closest('li').children('span');
  $target.add(this).toggleClass('hover', e.type == 'mouseenter');
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1A</li>
      <li>Item 1B</li>
      <li>Item 1C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2A</li>
      <li class="active">Item 2B</li>
      <li>Item 2C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 3A</li>
      <li>Item 3B</li>
      <li>Item 3C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that the `parent()` call is required before calling `closest()` as `closest()` will match the current `li` element, which we do not want, so `parent()` is required to 'hop' over that element.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it by:

- Using a standard `:hover` rule for the `li` itself
- Using a class, not direct styling, for its parent `li`
- Re-asserting the color for the subordinate `ul` elements (and thus their children) under the `li` with the class in the CSS

Like this:

```js
$("li")
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).parent().closest("li").addClass("has-active");
    }
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).parent().closest("li").removeClass("has-active");
    }
  });
```

```css
li {
  color: black;
}

li.has-active {
  color: red;
}

li.active:hover {
  color: red;
}

.has-active ul {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1A</li>
      <li>Item 1B</li>
      <li>Item 1C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2A</li>
      <li class="active">Item 2B</li>
      <li>Item 2C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3
    <ul>
      <li>Item 3A</li>
      <li>Item 3B</li>
      <li>Item 3C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```